# Keywords such as GENERATED are not available on Azure SQL Studio

Tags: azure-sql-database

After discovering the usefulness of [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15), I have tried to implement it using Azure SQL Data Studio.

However, I get syntax errors when using Keywords such as GENERATED or SYSTEM_VERSIONING.

[image]

Is there a fix for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of ADS are you using? It looks fine with the latest stable version (1.17.1) for me

[[image: 1]]

If you're still seeing this on the latest version please open an issue here https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues and we'll investigate.

Comment: turns out primary key is a "key" variable to solving. As for the unsolved references for the aforementioned keywords, I can just run them normally just that ADS dont have a reference for them